# jUnit Test fails although expected exception was thrown

Tags: exception, junit, automated-tests

this is how a test looks like in my application:

```
    @Test (expected = UniqueFieldValueConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void testName() {
       Branch b1 = new Branch("tetsname","Test 234","06:00-17:00","098144658");
       Branch b2 = new Branch("tetsname","Test 234","06:00-17:00","098144658");
       db.store(b1);
       db.store(b2);
       db.commit();
     }
```

This test fails although the exception is thrown:

> ```
> com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraintViolationException: class: dataModel.Branch field: pNumber     at
> ```
>
> com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraint$1.ensureSingleOccurence(UniqueFieldValueConstraint.java:66)
>     at
>   com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraint$1.onEvent(UniqueFieldValueConstraint.java:97)
>     at com.db4o.internal.events.Event4Impl.trigger(Event4Impl.java:78)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl$4.run(EventRegistryImpl.java:123)
>     at com.db4o.foundation.DynamicVariable.with(DynamicVariable.java:54)
>     at com.db4o.internal.InCallback.run(InCallback.java:24)     at
>   com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl.withExceptionHandlingInCallback(EventRegistryImpl.java:279)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl.commitOnStarted(EventRegistryImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.LocalTransaction.dispatchCommittingCallback(LocalTransaction.java:89)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.LocalTransaction.commit(LocalTransaction.java:66)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.LocalTransaction.commit(LocalTransaction.java:59)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.LocalObjectContainer.commitTransaction(LocalObjectContainer.java:689)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.LocalObjectContainer.close2(LocalObjectContainer.java:94)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.close1(ObjectContainerBase.java:361)
>     at
>   com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.close(ObjectContainerBase.java:344)
>     at tests.BranchTests.cleanUp(BranchTests.java:127)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

How can i avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace, you can see this exception isn't being thrown in the `testName()` method: it's being thrown by `tests.BranchTests.cleanUp`, which is presumably a separate method run before or after your real test.

JUnit's `expected` won't cover exceptions thrown during these phases. Either ensure these failures don't happen here, or catch and ignore them.

Comment: thx, this exception was created, like you have mentioned, in he cleanup() method. Eclipse marked the testname() method as failed and i never checked the details in the stack trace.